# How can I Run angular app on asp net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I want to run the angular app with asp net core and I use UseSpa() middleware like this:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    //spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

but I get this error :

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      - Generating browser application bundles...
```

when I serve angular app Separately and use

```
spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
```

everything is ok.

Package.JSON :

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "conventional-changelog": "conventional-changelog",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod --aot"
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

1. how  can I use `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")` and how can I see error log completely?
2. what is difference between `spa.UseAngularCliServer()` and `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably the same one as this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6342#issue-395713046. This answer puts it more succinctly: [Failed to start 'npm': Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367072/failed-to-start-npm-ensure-that-npm-is-installed-and-can-be-found/65182076#65182076), even though the actual error message here is misleading.

Basically, the Angular SPA template uses the wrong path for your IIS Express environment, which is what local development in ASP.net uses by default.  You'll need to correct the path as per the recommendations above.

For your second question, I googled them both (which I assume you did too) and I can't find any practical difference.  It looks like UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer() is a shortcut to the second overload of UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer() found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.spaproxyingextensions.useproxytospadevelopmentserver?view=aspnetcore-5.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion....but your first error indicates an error in your Angular application that is inside your ASP.NET application. I would reinstall the Angular CLI inside your Angular root folder as it might repair some missing node_modules folders.

```
cd c:\{path to your angular root folder}
npm install @angular/cli
```

See if that fixes use of your `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");` issue because I do not see anything wrong in your code.

As for the `spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");` code, that is a subset of `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");`. `UseAngularCliServer` first calls the Angular CLI to start a build and then proxy all ASP.NET requests to Angular running your application in-memory. So `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` only runs in ASP.NET if your `npm start` Angular CLI call has successfully built your Angular application in memory, started the Angular dev server, and loaded it up locally on a dynamic port.

The reason `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` worked when you separated Angular from ASP.NET is because that Angular instance must have been built successful before and was running a successful Angular build in memory in a dev server instance. That must be true because ASP.NET just sends or proxies all `localhost` calls to the Angular dev server running, which by default is port 4200.

The different between `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` and `UseAngularCliServer` is that the first call is a subset of the second.

`UseAngularCliServer` calls your `packages.json` "start" command which is just a "ng server" Angular CLI call. It handles the building of Angular in-memory which also calls and starts the `Angular Development Server` which runs your Angular build in-memory. After Angular is running, `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` is called behind the scenes, which passes requests by ASP.NET in the pipeline to the Angular dev server.